# Disabling double click on winform button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a windows form application in C#.Net. There are multiple forms in the application. Main form say frmA has a push button say btnA. On clicking btnA, new form say frmB is opened and frmA goes behind frmB. frmB also has a push button say btnB and position (location) of btnB on frmB is exactly same as that of btnA on frmA. On clicking btnB, some different actions take place.

Now my problem is some of application users double click on btnA. I get two single clicks back to back. On first single click on btnA, frmB is opened with btnB. Second single click is immediately executed on btnB and in effect users don't even get to see frmB.

My constraint is I cannot change locations of buttons on either forms. Is there anyway I can handle this problem?

Comment: You could start a timer with a small duration during which you don't handle any more clicks.

Comment: You could bind the [Button.DoubleClick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.doubleclick.aspx) and suppress it.

Comment: Attach a double-click event and from that event just call the default single click event which makes both single and double click do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do some trick, What about changing the `cursor position`. Once user click on btnA cursor point will be shifted a little so the second click will not hit the btnB.

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50);
Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to fire new form into different position.

As i've understood user is firing frmB on first click
and pressing btnB on "second click"

It's not double click.

It's two different clicks
try something like that:

```
Form2 form=new Form2();  
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;  
form.Location=new Point(0, 10);  
form.Show();
```

Comment: He clearly wrote he cannot change the position of the buttons.

Comment: OK. But i've written about changing position of new window.
Just to open it higher or lower from the main form

Answer (score 1):

Set btnB.Enabled to false and use the following code. This will delay the possibility to click the button for half a second.

```
public partial class frmB : Form
{
    private Timer buttonTimer = new Timer();

    public frmB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(buttonTimer_Tick);
        buttonTimer.Interval = 500;
    }

    private void frmB_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonTimer.Start();
    }

    void buttonTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnB.Enabled = true;
        buttonTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

disable it on the first click enable it when the user open again the forma or it come from forma to form b

```
this.button.enable=false;
```

immediately after pressing the button.
and write again in the constructor of forma

```
this.button.enable=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this UI is not friendly but if you absolutely cannot change the position of the buttons or the open position of the second form then you need to stop the second click causing the closure of frmB.  Easiest way would be to build in a delay upon opening formB e.g.

```
public partial class FormB : Form
    {
        public FormB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IMessageFilter to detect WM_LBUTTONDOWN messages and suppress them if they occur within a certain time threshold:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(new DoubleClickSuppressser());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f2.Location = this.Location;
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("listBox1 DoubleClick");
    }

}

public class DoubleClickSuppressser : IMessageFilter
{

    private int difference;
    private DateTime Last_LBUTTONDOWN = DateTime.MinValue;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                if (Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd) is Button)
                {
                    if (!Last_LBUTTONDOWN.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
                    {
                        difference = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(Last_LBUTTONDOWN).TotalMilliseconds;
                        Last_LBUTTONDOWN = DateTime.Now;
                        if (difference < System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    Last_LBUTTONDOWN = DateTime.Now;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Note that I've specifically disabled Double Clicking only for Buttons with the Control.FromHandle() check.  This will allow double clicks to work on other controls such as ListBoxes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

In your own class, inherit the base control and use the .SetStyle() method to disable the double-click.  The below code isn't for a Button, but it should work the same:

```
public class MOBIcon : PictureBox
{
    public MOBIcon() : base()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with enabling and disabling the button is that if the code you have in the click event runs so fast that the button gets enabled before the second click of the double click action (some users don't understand that it only takes 1 click) so here is my solution.

```
private const int waittime = 2;
private DateTime clickTime = DateTime.Now;

private void cmd_TimeStamp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ((DateTime.Now - clickTime).Seconds < waittime)
    return;
  else
    clickTime = DateTime.Now;
  try
  {
    cmd_TimeStamp.Enabled = false;
    //Do some stuff in here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //Show error if any
    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
  finally
  {
    cmd_TimeStamp.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```